# How to create this UI using UICollectionView so that content isn't restricted by Cell boundaries

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I need this functionality in my app. I think this can be achieved with `UICollectionView`, but the problem is that if I take 3 cells in each row, how can I achieve the spacing between the middle elements? Like the space between the cooking element and fitness is overlapping. Any useful links or advice for this?

[image: This is the cell arrangement I need]

Comment: I found something similar https://github.com/cyrilchandelier/CCHexagonFlowLayout , but in hexagonal layout rather than circular. I think this link may help you in some way. If you could solve your query, please update your question with answer.

Comment: Strictly considering this an opinion based question, there are *many* ways this can be achieved. Using a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class here is the optimal solution (IMO). One "hacky" solution is to apply a transform on the collection view, and a transform on each cell. The collection in this will scroll horizontally, but after applying the transform, it'll seem like it is vertical.
tinker around a bit with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach would be to embed three UICollectionViews in a wrapper UICollectionView(). 
[image]

1. Take a wrapper UICollectionView and bind it to the window (or parent view) edges -

   ```
   if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
       let wrapperCollectionView = UICollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)
       wrapperCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height)
       window.addSubview(wrapperCollectionView)
   }
   ```
2. Add a background blurring effect using UIBlurEffect()
3. From `numberOfItemsInSection` of wrapperCollectionView `return 3`
4. Create an array of UICollectionViews

   ```
   let gridCollectionViews: [UICollectionViews]!  
   // Make this global variable so that you can refer to the 
   // individual `UICollectionViews` by the indexes later gridCollectionViews[0] , [2] , [2]
   ```
5. In wrapperCollectionView.viewDidLoad() instantiate the 3 CollectionViews

   ```
   collectionViewCol1 = UICollectionView()
   collectionViewCol2 = UICollectionView()
   collectionViewCol3 = UICollectionView()
   ```
6. Inside `wrapperCollectionView.cellForItemAt` method, add the 3 UICollectionViews sequentially and bind them to the cells edges
7. Inside the `viewDidLoad` of the `collectionViewCol2`, give a `.contentOffset` equal to 1/2 of cellHeight -

   ```
   collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5 * cellHeight, 0, 0, 0)
   // collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5 * cellHeight, 0, 0, 0)
   // scrollIndicatorInsets won't be required since you're not showing the scroll indicators
   ```
8. Disable scrolling in subviews while keeping scrolling enabled in the wrapperCollectionView. Set all backgrounds except for the blurring-effect-view to `UIColor.clear` so that you get the blur effect.
9. Layout the cells in each UICollectionView

Comment: how can I set contentOff of ColletionViewCell and where?

Comment: Added info to the answer.

Comment: Did it work for you or you took another approach? I didn't test this. hope it doesn't have typos.

Comment: I didn't get the approach to use 3 collectionViews in a wrapperview and then again embed it into the collectionView.